# Python3 can't see opencv-python, numpy, PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, numpy, opencv

I installed opencv-python numpy PyQt5 using brew. Unfortunately it installed only for python in version 2 but I wanted it to ver 3. So normally when I am using python2 I can import those libs, but in python3 there is just error about not module found.

When I am typing for example brew info numpy, I am getting something like this:

```
numpy: stable 1.15.2 (bottled), HEAD Package for scientific computing with Python https://www.numpy.org/ /usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.15.2 (967 files, 25.5MB)   Poured from bottle on 2018-10-15 at 12:13:26 From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/numpy.rb
    ==> Dependencies Build: gcc ✔ Recommended: python ✔, python@2 ✔
    ==> Options
    --without-python    Build without python support
    --without-python@2  Build without python2 support
    --HEAD  Install HEAD version
    ==> Analytics install: 33,262 (30d), 96,001 (90d), 314,869 (365d) install_on_request: 5,934 (30d), 19,037 (90d), 56,029 (365d) build_error: 0 (30d)
```

So like you can see there is just python2 in "Recommended". Is there any possibility to repair this mistake and link somehow those libs to python3?

I am using macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Recently, Python.org sites stopped supporting TLS version 1.0 and 1.1. This helped:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `pip3` for installing packages for python3? Brew is for installing applications, not libraries.

Comment: With pip3 I always getting similar errors:
"MacBook-Pro:~ mok$ pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy"